# solving linear complex system of equations

Tags: matlab

Suppose my system of equations looks like:

```
A(1+2i) + B(100i) =10i;
CONJ(A)*(11i) +B(12+ 17i)= 167;
```

where `A` and `B` are complex numbers;

How do I solve for `A` and `B` using MATLAB? (I need to solve a system of 10 equations.)

Comment: I think you should solve it for `A`, `A*`, 'B' and `B*` using `linsolve`

Comment: I am finding difficulty with conjugate(A). Can you please elaborate how linsolv helps?

Answer (score 2):

This is a math problem. Basically you have four equations in four unknowns once you separate real/imag components

```
A*(1+2i) + B*(100i) =10i;
CONJ(A)*(11i) +B*(12+ 17i)= 167;
```

is equivalent to

```
   real(A) - 2*imag(A)                 - 100*imag(B) =  0
 2*real(A) +   imag(A) +  100*real(B)                = 10
            11*imag(A) +   12*real(B)  -  17*imag(B) = 167
11*real(A)             +   17*real(B)  +  12*imag(B) = 0
```

Then define the coefficients *x= [real(A) imag(A) real(B) imag(B)]* in your linear equations and solve for them as

```
A= [1   -2    0  -100
    2    1  100     0
    0   11   12   -17
   11    0   17    12];

b = [0 10 167 0]';

A\b

ans =

  0.4049
 14.7920
 -0.0560
 -0.2918
```

so `A=0.4049+14.7929i`, `B = -0.0560 -0.2908i`

with some mean rounding errors.

Of course this is not very helpful if you have 10 complex equations (20 equations in 20 unknowns). However you can rewrite the system above as

```
    real(A)                 -   2*imag(A)  - 100*imag(B)  =  0
            +   12*real(B)  +  11*imag(A)  -  17*imag(B)  = 167
  2*real(A) +  100*real(B)  +     imag(A)                 = 10
 11*real(A) +   17*real(B)                 +  12*imag(B)  = 0
```

and defining

```
D= [(1+2i)    (100i) 
     (11i)  (12+17i) ]; 

c = [10i 167]';
```

(from the original system *Dx=c*) one recognizes that this is *E*x_=f* with

```
E = [ real(D) -imag(D) 
      imag(D)  real(D) ];

f =  [real(c) ; imag(c)];
```

except that some terms have signs switched due to the conjugation operation. That can be taken care off separately by multiplying array `E` by an appropriate matrix of `ones` with the sign inverted for terms involved in a complex conjugate operation. This can be done as follows. Define a matrix `conj` containing `1` at locations in the original pair of equations where the conjugate operation is applied:

```
conj=[ 0 0
       1 0];
```

Then the sign matrix is

```
sgn = 2* ([ imag(conj) -real(conj) 
           real(conj)  imag(conj)]+1 >0)-1;
```

and the solution is

```
(E.*sgn)\f

ans =

    0.4049
   -0.0560
   14.7920
   -0.2918
```

Comment: @user2718422 I posted what appears a matrix-based solution.